# Stack overflow after an exception in Control.LayoutUpdated if DispatcherUnhandledException is registered

Tags: c#, wpf

Recently, I was running into a problem which I'm still breaking my head over. In an application, I registered a dispatcher exception handler. In the same application, a third-party-component (`DevExpress Grid Control`) causes an exception within the event handler for `Control.LayoutUpdated`. I expect, that the dispatcher exception handler is triggered once. But instead, I get a stack overflow. I produced a sample without the third party component and discovered, that it happens in every WPF application.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    namespace MyApplication
    {
        /* App.xaml

            <Application 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="MyApplication.App"
                Startup="OnStartup" 
            />

        */
        public partial class App
        {
            private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
            {
                DispatcherUnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
                MainWindow = new MainWindow();
                MainWindow.Show();
            }
            private static void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        public class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private readonly Control mControl;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                var grid = new Grid();
                var button = new Button();

                button.Content = "Crash!";
                button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                button.Click += OnButtonClick;

                mControl = new Control();

                grid.Children.Add(mControl);
                grid.Children.Add(button);

                Content = grid;
            }

            private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mControl.LayoutUpdated += ThrowException;
                mControl.UpdateLayout();
                mControl.LayoutUpdated -= ThrowException;
            }

            private void ThrowException(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior? It happens with .NET framework 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5. I can't just wrap a `try-catch` around the `LayoutUpdated` event handler since it is in a third party component and I don't think, a stack overflow should happen.

Comment: Your code in `OnButtonClick` looks very nonsensical.

Comment: The third party component registers the event handler in the constructor. In this sample, it will never call mControl.LayoutUpdated -= ThrowException because a stack overflow happens before that.

Comment: I copied your code and didnt get a stack overflow...

Comment: Did your IDE break at throw new NotSupportedException() ? In this case, you might want to run it outside the IDE.

Comment: I still get the NotSupportedException (but in a MessageBox), so everything works fine, but a got like a ton of MessageBoxes and I had to close the process by taskmanager. Maybe this is the reason why you get a stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, that is the effect I can observe. If you want to see the actual stack overflow, comment the line with the message box and click the button. Then wait.

Comment: you could place `mControl.LayoutUpdated -= ThrowException;` in your ThrowException-method.

Comment: Since the LayoutUpdate event handler is living in a third party component and I'm just showing the problem with the minimal code required above, I don't think it's a suitable solution. Generally, the problem is about the weird stack overflow which happens whenever an exception is thrown in any LayoutUpdate event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Florian GI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658676/florian-gl) is right about the message box, but if instead of a message box you did something else (or nothing i.e. just set `Handled` to `true`) in the `OnDispatcherUnhandledException` method it still loops forever and doesn't get to the `mControl.LayoutUpdated -= ThrowException;` line.

So I thought I would have a little snop through the code with dotPeek...

When you call `UpdateLayout` on the control, ultimately it gets to the method `ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout` and a snippet of this method looks like this:

```
// ... some code I snipped
bool flag2 = true;
UIElement element = (UIElement) null;
try
{
    this.invalidateTreeIfRecovering();
    while (this.hasDirtiness || this._firePostLayoutEvents)
    {

        //... Loads of code that I think will make sure 
        // hasDirtiness is false (since there is no reason 
        // for anything remaining dirty - also the event is
        // raised so I think this is a safe assumption

        if (!this.hasDirtiness)
        {
          this.fireLayoutUpdateEvent();
          if (!this.hasDirtiness)
          {
            this.fireAutomationEvents();
            if (!this.hasDirtiness)
              this.fireSizeChangedEvents();
          }
        }
        //... a bit more
        flag2 = false;
    }
}
finally
{
    this._isUpdating = false;
    this._layoutRequestPosted = false;
    //... some more code
    if (flag2)
    {
       //... some code that I can't be bothered to grok
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Delegate) ContextLayoutManager._updateLayoutBackground, (object) this);
    }
}

// ... and for good measure a smidge more code
```

I'm going to take a punt and suggest that the _`firePostLayoutEvents` flag is true in your case.

The only place where `_firePostLayoutEvents` is set to false is in the `fireAutomationEvents` method so let's assume that somewhere before the end of the `fireAutomationEvents` method your exception is thrown (I would guess the `fireLayoutUpdateEvent` method) so this flag will not get set to false.

But, of course, the finally is outside the loop so it will not loop forever (and if it did you'd not get a StackOverflowException).

Right, onward, so we are invoking the `UpdateLayoutBackground` function, which actually just calls `NeedsRecalc` so let's look at that...

```
private void NeedsRecalc()
{
  if (this._layoutRequestPosted || this._isUpdating)
    return;
  MediaContext.From(this.Dispatcher).BeginInvokeOnRender(ContextLayoutManager._updateCallback, (object) this);
  this._layoutRequestPosted = true;
}
```

Rightyho, that is calling the UpdateLayoutCallback so squinting at that...

```
private static object UpdateLayoutCallback(object arg)
{
  ContextLayoutManager contextLayoutManager = arg as ContextLayoutManager;
  if (contextLayoutManager != null)
    contextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout();
  return (object) null;
}
```

Oooooh, that is interesting - it's calling `UpdateLayout` again - I would, therefore, hazzard a slightly educated guess that that is the root cause of your problem.

Therefore, I don't think there is anything much you can do about it I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination. I reviewed your research using .NET Reflector and I can confirm your observations. It seems that we have a problem within the BCL here. Sadly, I can't even wrap a try-catch around the code in the LayoutUpdated-handler since I'm working with a third-party component in which the original exception happens. I'll let the developer know about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about the following, but maybe it's a guess in the right direction.

In MSDN it sais:

> However, LayoutUpdated can also occur at run time during the object
>   lifetime, for a variety of reasons: a property change, a window
>   resizing, or an explicit request (UpdateLayout or ApplyTemplate).

So it might get also fired after a MessageBox has shown?

If thats the case a MessageBox would open through an unhandled exception, which fires the LayoutUpdated-EventHandler and this again raises an unhandled exception. This would lead to an endless loop and after a while to the stack overflow.

If you do not throw an unhandled exception in the LayoutUpdated-EventHandler, but call the MessageBox.Show()-method it also ends in an endless loop, what would proof my point.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm over four years late to the party, but maybe someone will find this useful...

Your application's dispatcher does not stop responding to input and layout events during the call to `MessageBox.Show()`.  The `LayoutUpdated` event fires any time there is any layout-related work to do, which happens far more often than you might expect.  It will continue to fire while the message box is displayed, and if whatever condition triggered the error continues to persist, new exceptions will be raised, and your handler will show more and more message boxes.  And because `MessageBox.Show()` is a blocking call, it's not going to disappear from the call stack until it returns.  Subsequent invocations of your handler will be pushed deeper and deeper into the dispatcher's call stack until it overflows.

You really have two separate problems:

1. Your code to display a crash dialog is reentrant.
2. Your application continues to raise exceptions on the dispatcher thread while your crash dialog is being displayed.

You could solve the first issue with a non-reentrant queue.  Rather than displaying the crash dialog immediately, have your handler place the exception in a queue.  Have your handler process the queue **only if** you are not already processing it farther up the stack.  This prevents multiple crash dialogs from being shown simultaneously, and should keep your call stack from growing too deep, thus avoiding your stack overflow issue.

To address the second problem, you should probably shut down the offending part of your application as soon as you see the first exception (and before you show the crash dialog).  Alternatively, you could devise a way to filter out duplicate exceptions and ensure that equivalent errors don't end up in the queue at the same time.  But given how rapidly the exceptions are recurring, I would choose the first option.

Keep in mind that you need to address **both of these issues**.  If you don't address the second issue, you'll likely end up trading in your `StackOverflowException` for an `OutOfMemoryException`.  Or you'll show an infinite number of crash dialogs, one after the other.  Either way, it'll be bad.